# Is ESP8266’s “station + soft-ap” mode same as WiFi Direct (P2P)?

Tags: android, arduino, wifi-direct, esp8266, wifip2p

I found an [example on github](https://github.com/2016SNUSATCANSAT/2015ARLISSSOURCECODE/blob/master/Drive%20test/drivetest/ESP8266_P2P.cpp), just jump to line 42 then you’ll see this:

```
ESP8266.println("AT+CWMODE=3");
```

***AT*** is the command set in ESP8266 module, and `AT + CWMODE=3` means initialize WiFi connection mode with both station and soft-ap modes.

p.s. The name of this example is called “ESP8266_P2P.cpp”.

Answer (score 3):

The "[Soft AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftAP)" part is the same as [WiFi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct). The "station" part just means that the WiFi Direct *backend* is the same WiFi module (as opposed to e.g. an ethernet connection).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try connecting Android device with Arduino by this mode.

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266 does not support the WiFi Direct specific protocols. It means that your Android phone won't see it under WiFi Direct. However, in most cases you don't need that.

Comment: Check out page 26:  http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=0a-esp8266_datasheet_en_v4.3.pdf%E3%80%82

Comment: I know it's stated in the documentation but I haven't seen any implementation of that. I believe it's stated there because of different meanings of 'WiFi Direct' words - different than this in Android.